# Laravel 5.1: Eloquent Authentication Using Two Distinct User Models/Tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

My app needs to support two types of users:

1. `regular` users , these are those who are subscribers (restaurants
   that use my app for managing their business). For these users, I
   have the out of box authentication (Laravel 5.1) set up. `email` and
   `password` are the fields I authenticate on. I maintain information
   about such users in my `users` table.
2. `guests`, these are people who
   visit the restaurants above, register to earn loyalty points, check
   their score, leave feedback, etc.  I maintain information about such
   users in my `guests` table. Authentication, in this case, is simple.
   I just use a `mobile_number` to authenticate them into the app.

I get that I can implement guest's authentication in a subdomain of my app, with different `Controllers` and `Views`.

What I don't get is, how can I use the `eloquent` database driver with the two distinct models? I see that we specify the model eloquent would be using through `config.auth.model`.  So, I'm assuming that we can only have one single model implementing authentication.

Is, what I trying to achieve, possible without implementing a custom driver?

Comment: **Short answer: No.** You need a custom driver for this. But that shouldn't be too hard to implement, as you can easily get inspiration from/or extend the current [`EloquentUserProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php).

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks for the speedy response. I was sure, this would be the short answer :)

Comment: @Bogdan Please write your comments as an answer, so I can give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**

You need a custom driver for this. But that shouldn't be too hard to implement, as you can easily get inspiration from/or extend the current [`EloquentUserProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php). You can also check out the answer to this other question:

> [Custom user authentication base on the response of an API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331421/custom-user-authentication-base-on-the-response-of-an-api-call/33419313#33419313)

The context is different than yours, but it may help getting a better grasp on the implementation approach (that is if you haven't done this before).