# Laravel Auth external data for login and register

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using the Laravel 5.2 Auth system coming up with this command :

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Although this works totally fine as is, my goal is to use an external API to perform login, registering and changing password while still being able to use the core function of the Auth class.

So taking the login for example, I want to use something like

```
function login(ApiController $api) {
     // This function return data or error code and message in JSON
     $login = $api->login([ $credentials['email'], $credentials['password']]);
     if($login->success) 
       // login successfully like normal Auth would do
     else 
       // redirect to main page with $login->message
}
```

By the way, I want to pass fields coming up from $login to the Auth class, like we can actually do Auth::user()->email giving us the email, I'd want to set value like "database field" but with my API JSON fields behind

I looked on the Internet and found something to do inside AuthController and something related to ServiceProvider, but I don't know how to follow my exact needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding my own Auth system...

Using session() and Input()

Comment: Can you give more info or put Prrof of Concept code somewhere on public repo?

Comment: Hi @gandra404, I simply created a Middleware checking wether a session(loginNumber) exist, and then act on it. The session is put by the login form via a function that simply check the validity of the credentials against my external API.

Comment: Thanks for info.
Where you store session(loginNumber)?

Comment: No problem ;) I use Laravel session() helper, it does all the work for me !

Comment: Hi! I'm really new to bulding APIs with laravel, could you give me the steps you took to get throught this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I will do the same.. all the solutions online are overly complicated using concept words I don't know like "guard" with little to no clear explanations which makes it all the more confusing. More details on how you did it would help however

Answer (score 4):

Adding a custom user provider would help in this case. There is no need to play with AuthController here. Check [this Laravel Docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers).

You will need to create a new User Provider which implements [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/UserProvider.php), specify it in *AuthServiceProvider* and update your *auth config* file accordingly.

Here are the links to the framework's default User Providers for reference :

1) [DatabaseUserProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php)

2) [EloquentUserProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php)

Comment: Hi, thanx for the direction. I followed this tutorial https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/ but I can't get how to use the functions to fit my needs after that?

Comment: How to fill the functions in the Provider?

Comment: That's where the code to play with your Auth API will go. If you scroll a bit on the [docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers), There are specification on what exactly goes into each method of the custom user provider.

Comment: I'm starting to being stuck...I followed the docs but I don't understand, in the retrieveByCrendentials() function I return the User class, but how to pass my data coming from the API to it ?? Here my functions  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30264abd59126c684df14ca3768fff7c9854592c

Comment: A custom user provider was the solution for me too. This answer explains the steps in way more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419313/1800213

Comment: That other StackOverflow is a bit useful, but dated from 2015 and the framework changed a lot since then, so it's quite confusing