# Laravel5.4 authenticate users from api source, i.e. without database table for user/admin

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel5.4  authenticate users from api source, i.e. without database table for user/admin. I expected JSON response from Api, after success  how to use the  Auth class  so that I can maintain the sessions and authentication just like database. Do I have to make custom auth? If so how will I initiate attempt method as it checks for database. I have made admin guard, Is there any way to accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41155678/3113599

Comment: Thanks Gaurav do I have to make custom middleware to authenticate from external api? Api response gives me token do I have to store that token in database to make auth driver and guard work?

Comment: Nop. A custom user provider is needed in this case. [Check docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers). At least intermediate knowledge of OOP would be required for this.

Comment: Do I need to define model in the providers? I have no database for users. I storing the token in session. I have three types of users i.e user, member,admin. I have made middleware to check for session or api response. now I am trying to make guard for every user so that it check for particular value from api response or session.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: either you manage it manually (bad decision for long term) where you store token in session and check using middleware or you make custom user provider and put all that logic in respective methods. This way you can continue using Laravel's Auth and Guard features normally.

Comment: How will auth works? guard needs drivers and providers. I can use  driver session but how will provide will work? I am using api made in java. In api session token is generated after proper authentication. So will It work for long term. One question- will auth work without database? I have gone through user providers but for it we too have to make service provider and without database table there cant be service provider. Thanks for help