# Laravel 5.4 custom user authentication base on an API call

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Been trying to incorporate an external authentication with Laravel's authentication and I don't seem to make it work

Read and tried this article I've found here in stackoverflow, [Custom user authentication base on the response of an API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331421/custom-user-authentication-base-on-the-response-of-an-api-call), based on this article I've successfully put the externally authenticated user info to Laravel's Auth System.

My problem is when I do login and use that credential to login to the external API(assuming we fetch successfully the user info from the API) and redirect to another page, `Auth::user()` don't seem to work and always return `null` value, it looks like the session is not persisting...

I have also tried creating custom session to put the return data from the API inside the ApiUserProvider to access it later in other routes, but the session becomes missing....

I hope some could help me, Thank you

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.4

**config/auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'api',
        ],
    ],
```

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('api', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new \App\Providers\ApiUserProvider($this->app['hash']);
        });
    }
}
```

**app/Providers/ApiUserProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class ApiUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    protected $hasher;

    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {

        $user = [];

        $post = [
            'username' => $credentials['username'],
            'password' => $credentials['password']
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sample.com/dev/admin/login'); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(isset($response['successful']) && $response['successful']) {
            $response['claims'] =  json_decode(base64_decode(explode('.', $response['token'])[1]));
            $response['password'] =  bcrypt($credentials['password']);
            $response['username'] =  $credentials['username'];
            $response['id'] =  $response['claims']->client_id;
            $response['remember_token'] =  null;

            $user = $response;
            session()->put($response['claims']->client_id, $response); //<--- I attempt to put it in session
        }

        $user = $user ? : null;

        return $this->getApiUser($user);
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        //$user = $this->getUserById($identifier);
        $user = session()->get($identifier);  //<---- attempted to retrieve the user, but session don't exists if I go in other route 
        return $this->getApiUser($user);
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
         return $this->hasher->check(
            $credentials['password'], $user->getAuthPassword()
        );
    }

    protected function getApiUser($user)
    {
        if ($user !== null) {
            return new \App\ApiUser((array) $user);
        }
    }

    protected function getUserById($id)
    {
        $user = session()->get($id);
        return $user ?: null;
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) { }
    public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token) { }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\SessionGuard;

class UserController extends Controller
{ 
     protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request));
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('username', 'password');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
         if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
             dd(auth());
             return "T";
         }

         return "F";
    }

    public function getCurrentUserInfo(Request $request)
    {
        dd(auth()); //<------------- user info no longer exist here
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you logging in the user?

Comment: Hi Maxwelln, Im still using the `Auth::attempt` to login and passed it to the custom service provider(that extends the UserProvider Class) and inside `retrieveByCredentials` method, I perform cURL passing the username and password, if the result of the cURL is successful, It will be authenticated 

You can refer to the link I've mentioned above.... I did very similar with that one.

I am just having trouble regarding persistence of the retrieved data from API

Thanks

Comment: @EnriqhoJuan Any update on this? I think you have to store the data into some storage(database, cache etc) and retrieve from there for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because I am using the api route when login that is why it is not storing in the info in its session in auth,

I have tried adding startsession middleware in api route and it work but I think it is not right because api route must be stateless.