# Laravel login without checking in database

Tags: laravel

How to edit the standard login in Laravel so being able to log users without actual search in database. There is an APi returning json response containing all the information about the user if such is found. I guess I need to edit the Users model but can not find any examples. I need everything else to remain the same but skipping the search into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default behavior of the Authentication mechanism by creating your own UserProvider. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) part of the Laravel documentation for details.

Comment: I have the Id but this is  not stored into the Laravel database but it is retrieved from another system through API. Imagine that the users table is located in another server where is hosted all the user information.

Comment: What you're looking for is to implement your own UserProvider then. Check out the docs starting here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

Comment: I tried such approach before posting this question here. However,  I did not found anything that is working. There are plenty of peple having the same issue and no  answer found so far. The closest thing  was the solution posted here but still not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331421/custom-user-authentication-base-on-the-response-of-an-api-call

Comment: This is the only solution to your problem, the answer has been found and provided in every one of these questions: Make an implementation of the UserProvider class. Try to implement it, and ask a more precise question with code examples if you get stuck on anything