# Laravel API Based Validation / Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am currently using a API to validate Login Credentials.

I have gotten to the point where I am sending username/password correctly.

This API will return a bolean, depending on if those credentials are correct.

Along with the entire user's information, including their address etc.

How can I correctly store this into Laravel Auth, so I can use Auth::user etc in blade?

I do NOT have Database access, only API access to validate user login details.

I cannot create a local - Laravel database, as this application has to be completely API based.

I am using Guzzle to query the API.

Comment: These sorts of broad architectural questions are not a good fit for SO. Please come back when you have a specific coding problem that has a concrete answer. In the meantime, other resources might help, such as the Laracasts forum. See also other more specific questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331421/custom-user-authentication-base-on-the-response-of-an-api-call) that may help.

Comment: try to use tokens on the other half of the API.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using JWT for authentication, implementing your own API Authentication can cause some security issues if not done right.

Also JWT for Laravel already has support for Laravels Authentication system