# Laravel Auth from external api user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331421/custom-user-authentication-base-on-the-response-of-an-api-call/33419313) stackOverflow post and I am using `laravel 5.8.38`. I did everything suggested here, but I am getting error,

```
Call to undefined method App\Auth\ApiUserProvider::check()
```

on,

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?